# Datepicker does not update ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, datepicker

So, I've put together a very simple datepicker:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">

<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker min-date="minDate" show-weeks="false" class="well well-lg" ng-model="dt">    </datepicker>
</div>

<p>Date: {{dt}}.</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('services', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('services').controller('DatepickerCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
$scope.toggleMin();
});
```

The datepicker loads correctly but the ng-model is not updated and the paragraph at the end of the markup shows a blank value for "dt".

I saw a few similar issues posted on GitHub (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/808, https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/784) but none of the solutions there solved the issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I am always suspicious when I see ng-model referencing something without a dot (.) in the name.  If your controller code has $scope.dt change it to:

```
$scope.form = {};
$scope.form.dt = null;
```

Then in your html change references from "dt" to "form.dt".  As Misko says if you have a ng-model without a dot you are doing it wrong.

Best of luck,

Jerry

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am new to AngularJS so I'll keep that in mind for future reference. That said, it doesn't seem to solve the problem here :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem before!
This stuff always drives me crazy.
In Angular, the way data-binding works and how views are updated is not too well documented.
But one thing I learned is that anytime you try to update the view using something that is not supported by Angular, you want to $watch the variable whose value is changing so that each time the value does change, Angular will call $digest() which runs through the changes and updates the view.

You can read more about $watch here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

So back to your case:

Try $watch() on the variable that will change (alternatively, you can use $watchGroup for multiple changing variables).
For instance:

```
$scope.$watch('minDate'), function(newVal, oldVal, scope){
    if(newVal != oldVal){
        scope.minDate = newVal;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I gave that a try and it didn't seem to have any effect. What's really weird is: the ng-model="dt" seems to work and update on other elements. For example, if I use the example date input field provided: <input type="text" ng-model="dt" /> I can see the value of that field update as I update the datepicker. But it won't output the date to the <p> tag in the example.

Comment: Well that's because dt isn't defined in your service nor controller!

Try creating a variable 'date' in your service and update the variable when the user changes the date.

Then, replace {{dt}} with {{date}} making sure that your service is properly injected into your controller and properly defined there as well.

To better help you, please create a plunkr :)

Comment: Holy cow, well this is bizarre... It seems to work in Plunkr...     http://plnkr.co/edit/oMLRpy6xaGxgAHpxKCEI?p=preview  ...I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Try Using that code,i always use [(ngModel)]:

```
    <datepicker min-date="minDate" show-weeks="false" class="well well-lg" [(ngModel)]="dt">    </datepicker>
```